# RODBC sqlSave not all columns

Tags: r, rodbc

How can I make sqlSave to write only a subset of columns.

I've a (MS-Access) table with e.g. columns A, B, C en D and if I send a sqlSave command with a data frame with columns A, B and D (no C) I get the message:

```
Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  :
  missing columns in 'data'
Calls: sqlSave -> sqlwrite -> odbcUpdate
```

(The columns in my table are all defined optional)

I can add a dummy column to my data frame with name C and value NA and sqlSave will be happy, but is there another way to do this? Are there arguments of `sqlSave` I can use? I can't find them in the documentation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I spent no more time to this (too busy). The workaround with the dummy column works fine for me

Comment: @waanders i know it has been long, but is there any solution to this, other than updating all the columns ?

Comment: @Jack Sorry, I haven't used R for years